# Basic file version diff algorithm

Tags: c#, file, diff, version

I'm looking for a solution to compare two versions of the same file to get a representation of the changes/differences.

Comment: Any kind of byte-array. Text, images etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If it's plain text, then Google's [diff-match-patch](https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) library ought to do what you want (it has a C# version).

If it's binary data, then look into the things people do to apply updates to executables ([bsdiff](http://www.daemonology.net/bsdiff/) and [Courgette](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/software-updates-courgette)).  They look for the minimum difference between two files so that a smaller update can be sent out to end users.  Sounds similar to your needs.

Comment: wow - that's way more helpful an answer than I expected to see here

Comment: Thanks Jeff! But what is the difference of comparing text and binary files? I mean its just arrays of bytes anyway isnt it?

Comment: I think the primary difference is that text works line-by-line and you are looking for a human-readable diff.  For binary files you're looking at changing the minimum number of bytes across the file with no consideration for humans

Comment: I tried out the c#-conversion on github.com/LogosBible/bsdiff.net and it worked splendidly! But, I noticed I can only path **up** a file, not **down** again. I need a method to revert a patched file back to its original as well. I wonder if its hard to make one self...

Answer (score 2):

For plain text files, you can find an open source implementation in c# here: https://github.com/mmanela/diffplex